# Method annotated with @Bean is called directly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a configuration file with 2 Beans provided below:

```
    @Bean
    public EmptyInterceptor hibernateInterceptor() {

        return new EmptyInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
                if (entity instanceof TenantSupport) {
                    ((TenantSupport) entity).setTenantId(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
                if (entity instanceof TenantSupport) {
                    ((TenantSupport) entity).setTenantId(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
                if (entity instanceof TenantSupport) {
                    ((TenantSupport) entity).setTenantId(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder factory, DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties) {

        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", hibernateInterceptor());

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean =  factory.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.monytyz.billing").properties(jpaPropertiesMap).build();
        return factoryBean;
    }
```

I get an error for the `hibenrateInterpretor` that Method annotated with @Bean is called directly. Use dependency injection instead.

This doesn't prevent me from compiling but how do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the bean as a parameter to the second bean, like this:

```
@Bean
public EmptyInterceptor hibernateInterceptor() {

    return new EmptyInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
            if (entity instanceof TenantSupport) {
                ((TenantSupport) entity).setTenantId(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
            if (entity instanceof TenantSupport) {
                ((TenantSupport) entity).setTenantId(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
            if (entity instanceof TenantSupport) {
                ((TenantSupport) entity).setTenantId(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder factory, DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties, EmptyInterceptor hibernateInterceptor) {

    Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
    jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", hibernateInterceptor);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = factory.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.dddytyz.billing").properties(jpaPropertiesMap).build();
    return factoryBean;
}
```